# Is there a way to get file owner name using Github api?

Tags: powershell, api, github, github-api

I am trying to fetch file owner details from github using github api. As of Now I am able to fetch the file owner name using api by invoking 2 calls - one call to get file details and 2nd call for getting commit details. Below is my powershell code for reference.

But 2 Issues I am facing in api calls:

1. Not sure how to change branch, Currently its picking default branch on github in search/code api call.
2. Sometimes the API call returns Null value and if we rerun, it gives proper output.

```
function GitUser-Details($filename, $repo) {

    $dt=(Get-Date).AddDays(-25).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
    $apiKey='git-token'
    $headers = @{}
    $headers.Add("Authorization","Bearer $apiKey")
    $headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github+json")

    $res=''
    $URI= "https://api.github.com/search/code?q=  filename:$filename   repo:Org-Name/$repo&per_page=100"
    $res=Invoke-RestMethod  -Method GET  -Headers  $headers -Uri $URI  
      
    $user=''

    if($res.items){

           $headers = @{}
           $headers.Add("Authorization","Bearer $apiKey")
           $headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github.sha") 

           $commitDetails=''

           $url=$res.items[0].url
           $sha=$url.Split('=')[-1]

           $URI= "https://api.github.com/search/commits?q= committer-date:>$dt hash:$sha repo:Org-Name/$repo&per_page=100"
           $commitDetails=Invoke-RestMethod  -Method GET  -Headers  $headers -Uri $URI  
      
           $user=$commitDetails.items.author.login
    }

    return $user
}

GitUser-Details $filename $repo
```

Please let me know how I can change branch while searching for code and also avoid null values?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "file owner"? The last user to make a change to that file? The first user to create that file?

Comment: To expand on @IMSoP's comment: in Git, individual files have no concept of "ownership". Each *commit* has two owners, an "author" and a "committer". Each commit has a full snapshot of every file. So you can ask, e.g., "which commit last changed this file in any way" or "which commit last changed this particular line of this particular file" and use that information to display the author or committer name of that commit, but that's not the "owner" of the file, which simply isn't defined. Whether there's a GitHub API to do these specific tasks, I have no idea.

Comment: Hi @torek,
                 Sorry for Delay. From File Owner - I mean the person name who did last commit . From the code I have mentioned earlier, I am able to find last committed person name but the api call only works for default branch. I want to know is there a way by which we can switch the branch? Moreover the mention api call returns null value but if I rerun it - it provide output. Is there a way to solve this issue and change branch?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm no GitHub API expert. You might consider reducing your question to a smaller one specifically about the GitHub API, given that nobody seems to have provided any answer to this one that requires someone to understand PowerShell as well.